# Homestead mysql slow quert

Tags: mysql, homestead

I have new instance of Laravel Homestead 5.4 with mysql 5.7.19.
When I connect to it with Mysql Workbench it runs ok but when i run a complicated query it takes a lot of time. The same query when I run it on different vagrant box with mysql 5.6 it finish in max 20 sec.

For the memory:
memory: 3072
cpus: 4

Comment: Have you tried the most basic of things such as rebooting the server? What have you tried so far.

Comment: yes I have also added in /etc/mysql/my.cnf `[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G 
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
sync_binlog = 0
`  and nothing

Comment: Well the problem seems to be with the old version of virtualbox 5.0, when I update to 5.1 it got a lot faster...

Answer (score 0):

This can not be answered in the absence of the QUERY and EXPLAIN EXTENDED or EXPLAIN.  Including SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name and SHOW INDEX FROM table_name for each table involved in the query would enable this community to be much more likely to produce an answer.

2017-08-19 7:30 CT USA Since there is no problem in your query, please run it as EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ....    followed by SHOW WARNINGS  , post in the original question please the QUERY, EXPLAIN EXTENDED and SHOW WARNINGS so we can see the order of execution.  We still need a look at each table and index availability, please.

Comment: the problem is not in the query. As I wrote the same query in mysql 5.6 executes under 20-30 sec top and here on 5.7 it execute over 5 min. and in the cases noting was done on the mysql server clean install and new Homestead.